# Proving metric( the triangle inequality)

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

In complex plane $\mathbb{C}$, how to prove that
$$d(z_1,z_2)=\frac{|z_2-z_1|}{\sqrt{1+|z_1|^2}\sqrt{1+|z_2|^2}}$$
is a metric?

I got stuck in the triangle inequality, and have no idea of proving it, any hint or solutions?

Thanks for replying!

Comment: You decribe the def. of $d$ correctly? I think this $d$ is not a metric, because $d(z_1,z_2)$ can be nonpositive real number (or even nonreal complex number.)

Comment: Do you mean $\lvert z_1 \rvert^2$? otherwise, e.g. for $z_1=i$, this isn't well-defined.

Comment: Oh yes， I mean $|z|^2$,sorry for my mistake.

Comment: See also: [How to show that the spherical metric satisfies the triangle inequality?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1090222/how-to-show-that-the-spherical-metric-satisfies-the-triangle-inequality)