# How to show that the spherical metric satisfies the triangle inequality?

Tags: metric-spaces

For $x,y\in \mathbb R^n$ define 
$$d(x,y)={\|x-y\| \over \sqrt{1+\|x\|^2} \sqrt{1+\|y\|^2}}$$
Here $\|x\|$ is the euclidean norm of a vector. How to prove that $d$ (the spherical metric) is indeed a metric?

---

Progress so far:

1. $d(x,y)\ge 0$ is obvious.
2. $d(x,y) =0 \iff \|x-y\|=0 \iff x=y$, so the positivity holds.
3. $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$ is clear from the formula, so symmetry holds.

But I am having difficulties with the triangle inequality. Writing it out in coordinates leads to a complicated inequality with square roots all over the place in denominators. Is there a better way?

Comment: Cauchy Schwartz inequality ?

Comment: Haven't tried that, how would it look?does it work?

Comment: @Suzu Hirose I apologize for not being honest, i have tried that to no avail, like many other techniques as well. None have worked and i apologize again for not displaying my efforts for vividly for the rest to see. What does not work is not worth mentioning i believe. A lack of effort on my part is not present.

Comment: I would use [stereographic projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection#Definition): introduce 3D coordinates $u,v,w$ related to $x,y$ by the projection formulas; check that the distance function you have corresponds to the usual Euclidean distance in 3D space; conclude.

Comment: Very impressive way of seeing this. I'll definitely give it a try.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The quickest way I know is to "cheat"${}^*$ with [Stereographic projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection#Definition). Introduce the map $F:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^{n+1}$ defined by $F(  x)=( z,t)\in\mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R$ with 
$$  z=\frac{x}{1+\|x\|^2},\quad t= \frac{\|x\|^2}{1+\|x\|^2}$$
(This is a projection onto the sphere $\|z\|^2+(t-1/2)^2=1/4$, but this fact isn't needed.)
Direct computation shows that 
$$
\|F(x)-F(y)\|^2  = \frac{\|x\|^2}{(1+\|x\|^2)^2}+\frac{\|y\|^2}{(1+\|y\|^2)^2} - \frac{2x\cdot y}{(1+\|x\|^2)(1+\|y\|^2)} + \frac{1}{(1+\|x\|^2)^2}+\frac{1}{(1+\|y\|^2)^2} - \frac{2}{(1+\|x\|^2)(1+\|y\|^2)}$$
which simplifies to
$$
\frac{1}{1+\|x\|^2}+\frac{1}{1+\|y\|^2} - \frac{2x\cdot y}{(1+\|x\|^2)(1+\|y\|^2)}  - \frac{2}{(1+\|x\|^2)(1+\|y\|^2)}
$$
and subsequently to
$$
\frac{2+\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2-  2x\cdot y -2}{(1+\|x\|^2)(1+\|y\|^2)}  = {\|x-y\|^2 \over ( 1+\|x\|^2)\,(1+\|y\|^2)}
$$
Thus, $\|F(x)-F(y)\|=d(x,y)$, and the triangle inequality for $d$ follows from the triangle inequality for the Euclidean distance in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$.

---

$(*)$ I think this is not much cheating, because what use is this metric to us without knowing its relation to the sphere?

Comment: The proof uses inner products. It is interesting to ask if the result hods any normed linear space.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: That's an interesting question. Why don't you ask it in another thread?

Comment: I've now stared at this calculation for longer than I'd like to admit, but I do think that the $t$-coordinate needs to be defined as $t = \frac{1}{1 + \|x\|^2}$ instead. Otherwise it is not clear to me why you'd have terms with enumerators independent of $x$ and $y$ in the calculation of $\|F(x) - F(y)\|^2$. However, that would mean this map isn't directly related to stereographic projections anymore, I believe. Rather, we'd have the equation $\|z\|^2 + \|t\|^2 = \frac{1}{1 + \|x\|^2}$...